# Scholarships and SOP

Tags: funding, statement-of-purpose

Should I mention that my work is providing me with a full scholarship to study my masters in my Statment of purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably worthwhile to mention it:

Pros:

- If you work in a related field, this could be used to demonstrate
  that you are a good candidate since someone is prepared to pay for you
  because they think you are a good catch.
- It is also more generally not bad to show that you are a competitive
  applicant who has attracted awards for past performance.
- Finally, it suggests that you are serious about pursuing your Masters (have secured your own funding or at least will not be deterred by financial issues). That could also be helpful to the admissions people if they are concerned with acceptance rates into the program.

Cons:

- If the program has its own scholarship/funding you might take yourself out of the running for that and be committed to returning to work for your company after you graduate because you have used their scholarship.